# How to format a json response in desired form dynamically?

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel, codeigniter

I have a json form that will be used by clients.
For data objects, it's dynamic

but for **type** key array of objects not look dynamic yet. How to make **type** array of objects dynamically. Here I make json as follows:

```
{
    "status": 200,
    "error": false,
    "data": {
        "id": "xxxxxxx",
        "name": "xxxxxxx",
        "type": [
            {
                'brand'  :'silver',
                "price": "8500",
                "est": "1 -2 D"
            },
            { 
                'brand'  :'gold',
                "price": "15000",
                "est": "1 D"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

**Model**

```
public function db_paket_array_harga($param='',$param2=''){ 
    $hasil1=$this->db->query("SELECT abcd FROM a WHERE a='$param' AND b='$param2' LIMIT 1")->result();
      $tarif2[] = array(
        'brand'       => 'silver',
        'price'       => $hasil1[0]->reguler,
        'est'         => $hasil1[0]->etd_reg
      );
      $tarif2[] = array(
        'brand'      => 'gold',
        'price'      => $hasil1[0]->nextday,
        'est'        => $hasil1[0]->etd_nd
      );
      return $tarif2;
    }
```

**Model 2**

```
public function db_paket_array_harga($param='',$param2=''){ 
     $hasil = $this->db->query("SELECT abcd FROM a WHERE a='$param' AND b='$param2' LIMIT 1")->result(); 
     $hasil_satu = array();
        foreach ($hasil as $k) {
        $hasil = array( 
          'id'            => $hasil[0]->id_origin,
          'name'          => $hasil[0]->origin,
          'type'          => $this->db_paket_array_harga($param,$param2)
           //this is called the first model
        );
      }
```

**Controller**

```
public function price_get(){ 
        $param= $this->get('param');
        $param2= $this->get('param2');
        $res        = $this->My_model->db_paket($param,$param2);
        $this->response($res, 200);
    }
```

> How to make array of objects for **type** key dynamically?

thanks

Comment: What do you mean how to make it dynamically? Also can you also include your `db_paket` function in the question?

Comment: When I add a new field to the database, does it automatically add object types, for example I add a new brand?